# How to send FIX message with QuickFIX/J

Tags: java, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I need a simple example of how to initialize a session and send one FIX message. I have this initial code:

```
SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings( new FileInputStream("fix.cfg"));

Application application = new Application(settings);
MessageStoreFactory messageStoreFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
LogFactory logFactory = new ScreenLogFactory( true, true, true);
MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();

Initiator initiator = new SocketInitiator(application, messageStoreFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
initiator.start();
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the code above, I see that you have an initiator application (the client) and you need to also create an `acceptor` application (the server). Below I've attached the two classes that will do what do you want.

First I'll list the `acceptor` application:

```
public class ServerApplication implements Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SessionID sessionID) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogon(SessionID sessionID) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogout(SessionID sessionID) {
    }

    @Override
    public void toAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID) {
    }

    @Override
    public void fromAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, RejectLogon {
    }

    @Override
    public void toApp(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws DoNotSend {
    }

    @Override
    public void fromApp(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType {
        System.out.println("FromApp: " + message);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigError, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, SessionNotFound {
        SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings("res/acceptor.config");

        Application application = new ServerApplication();
        MessageStoreFactory messageStoreFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
        LogFactory logFactory = new ScreenLogFactory( true, true, true);
        MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();

        Acceptor initiator = new SocketAcceptor(application, messageStoreFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
        initiator.start();

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        latch.await();
    }
}
```

This is a server application that will stay started and listen for messages from the clients which connect to it. Here is the configuration file (`acceptor.properties`) used by it:

```
[default]
ApplicationID=server
FileStorePath=storage/messages/
ConnectionType=acceptor
StartTime=00:01:00 Europe/Bucharest
EndTime=23:59:00 Europe/Bucharest
HeartBtInt=30
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FIX42.xml
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ValidateIncomingMessage=N
RefreshOnLogon=Y

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SocketAcceptPort=9877
SenderCompID=server
TargetCompID=client
AcceptorTemplate=N
lockquote
```

---

Next is the client application code. It tries to connect to a server and after that it will send a message to it:

```
public class ClientApplication implements Application {

    private static volatile SessionID sessionID;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SessionID sessionID) {
        System.out.println("OnCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogon(SessionID sessionID) {
        System.out.println("OnLogon");
        ClientApplication.sessionID = sessionID;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogout(SessionID sessionID) {
        System.out.println("OnLogout");
        ClientApplication.sessionID = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void toAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID) {
        System.out.println("ToAdmin");
    }

    @Override
    public void fromAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, RejectLogon {
        System.out.println("FromAdmin");
    }

    @Override
    public void toApp(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws DoNotSend {
        System.out.println("ToApp: " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void fromApp(Message message, SessionID sessionID) throws FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType {
        System.out.println("FromApp");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConfigError, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, SessionNotFound {
        SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings("res/initiator.config");

        Application application = new ClientApplication();
        MessageStoreFactory messageStoreFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
        LogFactory logFactory = new ScreenLogFactory( true, true, true);
        MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();

        Initiator initiator = new SocketInitiator(application, messageStoreFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
        initiator.start();

        while (sessionID == null) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        final String orderId = "342";
        NewOrderSingle newOrder = new NewOrderSingle(new ClOrdID(orderId), new HandlInst('1'), new Symbol("6758.T"),
                new Side(Side.BUY), new TransactTime(new Date()), new OrdType(OrdType.MARKET));
        Session.sendToTarget(newOrder, sessionID);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

The configuration file for it (`initiator.config`) is almost the same as the one used for the acceptor:

```
[default]
ApplicationID=client
FileStorePath=storage/messages/
ConnectionType=initiator
StartTime=00:01:00 Europe/Bucharest
EndTime=23:59:00 Europe/Bucharest
HeartBtInt=30
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FIX42.xml
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ValidateIncomingMessage=N
RefreshOnLogon=Y

[session]
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SocketConnectHost=localhost
SocketConnectPort=9877
SenderCompID=client
TargetCompID=server
```

The configuration files both miss some options, but for testing purposes are enough. Each of the classes has a main method added just for testing the case you wanted.

Normally you would handle a bit different the way they are started or stopped. The server application listens for messages/connections and is never stopped, while the client application stops right after sending the first message.

Answer (score 7):

There are examples included in the installation of QuickFIX/J, namely `Executor` and `Banzai`. You can read about that [here](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/examples.html).

> QuickFIX comes with several example applications. These application are in the **quickfix/examples** directory. They are not meant to demonstrate good application design or meant to be used in a real production system. They are merely provided as a tutorial on how to build an application with QuickFIX.
>
> **Executor** is a very simple order execution simulator. It only supports limit orders and always fills them completely.
>
> **Banzai** is a simple trading client. It can be used with the Executor to see a simple example of using QuickFIX/J on both the buy and sell side of an order execution.

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Updated, though I guess I'll have to update every few major updates